# Formula to convert date to number

Tags: excel, date, number-formatting

I would like to know the formula to convert a date in 10/26/2013 to 41573 number as done in Excel.

Like how 10/26/2013 is converted to 41573.

Comment: It is the number of days since January 1, 1900. The function used in Excel is `DATEVALUE`. It will return days and fractional days (so noon on 10/26/2013 would be 41573.5).

Comment: My problem is a bit different; I have a `datetime` value in the excel and when I convert it to text, it returns `42278.0034722`. How can I calculate the time?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you change the format of the cells to General then this will show the date value of a cell as behind the scenes Excel saves a date as the number of days since 01/01/1900

[image: Screenprint 1]

[image: Screenprint 2]

If your date is text and you need to convert it then `DATEVALUE` will do this:

[image: Datevalue function]

Answer (score 24):

The Excel number for a modern date is most easily calculated as the number of days since 12/30/1899 on the Gregorian calendar.

Excel treats the mythical date 01/00/1900 (i.e., 12/31/1899) as corresponding to 0, and incorrectly treats year 1900 as a leap year. So for dates before 03/01/1900, the Excel number is effectively the number of days after 12/31/1899.

However, Excel will not format any number below 0 (-1 gives you ##########) and so this only matters for "01/00/1900" to 02/28/1900, making it easier to just use the 12/30/1899 date as a base.

A complete function in DB2 SQL that accounts for the leap year 1900 error:

```
SELECT
   DAYS(INPUT_DATE)                 
   - DAYS(DATE('1899-12-30'))
   - CASE                       
        WHEN INPUT_DATE < DATE('1900-03-01')  
           THEN 1               
           ELSE 0               
     END
```

Comment: Coyne - I just spent an hour trying to sort out the two-day offset.  Thank you so much for your explanation! Well done.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! 
If somebody else needs it for converting the Excel time to UTC time (to be read as a CSV in JavaScript), I've explained it [in a gist](https://gist.github.com/erikvullings/825283249a5b4617d0f36bcba4fa8be8).