# How to get the date from a 5 digit number

Tags: objective-c, battery

From my code, i get manufacture date as below:

```
.....
   - (NSDictionary *)getBatteryInfo
   {
    matching = IOServiceNameMatching("AppleSmartBattery");
    entry = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault, matching);
    IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties(entry, &properties, NULL, 0);
    return (__bridge NSDictionary *)properties;
   }
......

  NSDictionary *Info = [self getBatteryInfo];

  NSNumber *manufacturerDate = [Info objectForKey:@"ManufactureDate"];
```

I tried these codes in a macbook and get 17492 for the date, and I also check the date with a app installed from App store and know the exact date is 2014/02/20.

In another macbook, i get 16727 for the date, and the exact date is 2012/10/23.
Who can tell me how to calculate the exact date with this 5 digit number.

Comment: They appear to be the number of days since some epoch but the difference between the two numbers is 765 but the difference in days between those two dates is far less than 765. Are you sure those are the right dates for those two numbers?

Comment: Its number of days from 01/01/1900. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721416/formula-to-convert-date-to-number

Comment: @Mrunal It can't be. 17492 days from 1900 would be about in the year 1947, not 2014.

Comment: Hmmm true, that is for excel stuffs, it is different than this value. Sorry for my bad.

Comment: @rmaddy yes, i am sure the data is correct. That's why i am so confused. Do you have any good suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Date is published in a bitfield per the Smart Battery Data spec rev 1.1 in section 5.1.26 ([see](http://www.publicsource.apple.com/source/PowerManagement/PowerManagement-420.1.20/AppleSmartBatteryManager/AppleSmartBatteryCommands.h?txt))

- Bits 0...4 => day (value 1-31; 5 bits)
- Bits 5...8 => month (value 1-12; 4 bits)
- Bits 9...15 => years since 1980 (value 0-127; 7 bits)

**UPD. Example**

17492 is in binary notation 0100010001010100 (unsigned interpretation for 16-bit number). So,

- Bits 0...4 => 10100 => 20 day
- Bits 5...8 => 0010 => 2 month
- Bits 9...15 => 34 + 1980 = 2014 year

Thus, we've got that 17492 is **2014/02/20**

Comment: so in this place, the 17492 means 17492 days since a exact date? Do you know what is the start date?

Comment: @jimwan no. I've added an example, see above

Comment: The start date seems to be Jan 1st 1970