# Kendo UI grid exporting date column data as ###############

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui, grid

****example: http://jsfiddle.net/o8cw3vj8/12/
I am trying to export kendo ui grid and grid has date column, when exported it contains only ############... when date year is less than or equal to 1900
Thanks,****

```
 $("#grid1").kendoGrid({
   toolbar: ["excel"],
   excel: {
     fileName: "Kendo UI Grid Export.xlsx",
     proxyURL: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/export",
     filterable: true
   },
   dataSource: {
     data: [{
       "Id": 1,
       "Name": "John",
       "DOB": "01/01/1753"
     }, {
       "Id": 2,
       "Name": "Joe",
       "DOB": "01/01/1953"
     }, {
       "Id": 3,
       "Name": "Jack",
       "DOB": "01/01/1940"
     }],
     schema: {
       model: {
         fields: {
           Id: {
             type: "number"
           },
           Name: {
             type: "string"
           },
           DOB: {
             type: "date"
           }
         }
       }
     }
   },

   columns: [
     "Id", "Name", "DOB"
   ]
 });
```

Comment: Is this export to Excel? Excel shows a string of hashes when column is too narrow for the value: try adjusting Excel's column width.

Comment: On further thought: that's wrong. Excel can only handle dates from 1900-01-01: anything before then will just be a negative number that Excel cannot handle as a date.

Comment: yes the problem is Excel can only handle dates from 1900-01-01.

Answer (score 0):

If you hover the cell you will see a message "Dates and times that are negative or too large display as #####". Here is a screenshot:

[image]

This happens because [Excel saves dates as numbers of days after 1/1/1990](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19722948/10141). In your case the numbers become negative hence the display.