# Date conversion issue in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, sql-server-2012

I am trying to convert numeric value to date. I have search for it found below answer

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(FLOAT, 41547))
```

Output which I got is **2013-10-02 00:00:00.000**

But if I check the date value of **41547** in excel It gives me **2013-09-30**, which is 2 days less than what I get in SQL Server.

Please help me to understand this conversion.
How can I get **2013-09-30** instead of **2013-10-02** for number **41547**.

Comment: This is probably due to the fact you cast the value to a `float`, which is an approximate datatype. If you cast instead to an `integer`, what do you get?

Comment: I forgot to modify ,I use float as well as int both gives me same result.

Comment: You're right, I get the same results, also for excel. I don't know how excel does the conversion, but I'd trust sql-server more...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Excel treats the mythical date 01/00/1900 (i.e., 12/31/1899) as corresponding to 0, and incorrectly treats year 1900 as a leap year. So for dates before 03/01/1900, the Excel number is effectively the number of days after 12/31/1899.
>
> Excel will not format any number below 0 (-1 gives you ##########) and so this only matters for "01/00/1900" to 02/28/1900, making it easier to just use the 12/30/1899 date as a base.

*Reference from this* [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32848723/2451726)

So in your SQL Server you need to add the days *(41547 in your case)* from the **12/30/1899** like the below and it will give the same result as return from the excel.

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 41547, '1899-12-30')
```

It will result as **2013-09-30 00:00:00.000**

If you don't want the timestamp in the result and expect the same format from excel **2013-09-30** then use the convert as

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY ,41547, '1899-12-30'), 111), '/', '-')
```

Comment: Just one more doubts Is this conversion issue only in SQL server or it is with other database also like oracle,mysql..???

Comment: @dreamer Please refer this for [Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398908/change-excel-date-number-to-oracle-date)